# CQ5 - How to get the page Image

Tags: java, image, aem

I'm fairly new to CQ5, and I've got the following problem.

I'm trying to display a list with the images behind the childpages. I managed to get the list itself working, but there's something wrong with the images, the path to it isn't correct .

So far I've got this

```
<div class="img-list">
  <img src="${list.img}" />
</div>
```

and

```
public class ImageList {
private String img = "";
private Page listItem;
String extension;
Resource r;

public ImageList(Page p ) {
    this.listItem = p;
    this.r = listItem.getContentResource("image");

}

public String getImg() {

    if (r != null) {
        //Image image = new Image(r);
        img = r.getPath();
    }

    return img;
}

public void setImg (String i) {
    this.img = i;
}

}
```

But this isn't working. Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance

Edit, got it working with the following solution:

```
public String getImg() {
    String imagePath = "";
    if (r != null) {
       Image image = new Image(r);
        imagePath = (String)listItem.getPath()+".img.png"+ image.getSuffix();
    }
    return imagePath;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to get a list of images from the child pages.

Why not try creating a **Page** object, which is mapped to your current page (essentially, a current page object) and then use the ***listChildren*** method to list out all of the child pages. Then you can use the page.getContentResorce("image") method, create an image object and then return the path for images associated with each child page..

Something like this:-

```
Iterator<Page> childPageIterator = Currentpage.listChildren(new PageFilter(request));
while(pageIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Page childPage = pageIterator.next();
                         Resource r = page.getContentResource("image");
                         if (r != null) {
                            Image image = new Image(r);
                            String imagePath = (String)contentpage.getPath()+".img.png"+ image.getSuffix();
                         }
            }
```

You may need to tailor this as per your needs, but hopefully this should get you started

Comment: Getting the children isn't the problem. The problem is showing the image. I just tried a somewhat modified version of your solution, and the output is <img src>. Also, I'm not trying to get the children from the current page. I'm using the children of a different page.

Comment: Nevermind, made a small typo, I just used String imagePath = (String)contentpage.getPath()+".img.png"+ image.getSuffix(); in my original solution and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the path of the resource(image node) and provide it to the src attribute of the image tag, instead of the providing the actual path of the image.

One way of approaching this by changing the getImg() method as shown below

```
public String getImg() {
    if (r != null) {
        Node node = r.adaptTo(Node.class);
        if(node.hasProperty("fileReference"){
            img = node.getProperty("fileReference").getString();
        }
    }
    return img;
}
```

Or you can use the **com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Image class** to draw the image by passing the resource object, instead of using the **img** tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But when I do this, the output is <img src>, nothing more. And I'm sure there's an image on those childpages. Any ideas?